# How find() and find_all() methods work in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = "https://realpython.github.io/fake-jobs/"
page=requests.get(URL)
#print(page.text)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
results = soup.find(id="ResultsContainer")
python_jobs = results.find_all(
"h2", string=lambda text: "python" in text.lower())
```

This piece of code works well but I dont understand the last two lines.

I intend to search string which containing `"python"`, but the lambda function returns either `True` or `False` which means string=`"True"` or `"False"`.
In my point of view, I would write something like: `string=text if "python" in text`.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Is the question actually anything to do with BeautifulSoup, or are you just trying to understand what `lambda text: "python" in text.lower()` means?

Comment: "but the lambda function return either True or False which means string="True‘ or "False"" No. The lambda is **not called** at this point. `string` is equal **to the lambda**. `results.find_all` will take that lambda and call it for you, several times. Depending on whether it gets `True` or `False` results, it will determine the resulting list of matching text.

Comment: What are you trying to use lambda? why not use `python_jobs = results.find_all(
"h2", string="python".lower())` ?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I misunderstood lambda function here.@KarlKnechtel

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.